# tastypie custom authorization read_detail not being used

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a custom Authorization class that I have subclassed from `tastypie.authorization.Authorization` and for which I am currently writing unit tests. In testing the read_detail() method, I've discovered a particular request for which my read_detail() method is not being consulted and a status code of 200 is being returned (with the correct payload.

I've ensured that none of the other *_detail or *_list methods are being executed instead. How can I go about effectively debugging this issue?

EDIT:

Disabling SimpleCache made the problem go away....